# Cross browser solution for insetting button outline when focussed

Tags: css

I have a 100% width button at the bottom of my page. If I use the tab key to move focus to my button, the browsers default outline appears. In the example below, its the blue outline used in the Chrome browser:

Markup

```
<button>
  <font-awesome-icon icon="arrow-circle-down" size="2x" />
</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: grey;
  color: blue;
  border: 0;
}
```

[image]

As you can see the outline is pushed off the page on the sides and on the bottom.

If I do: `outline-offset: -3px;`. This appears to fix the  problem for Chrome.

Is there a rule that will work across all browsers?

Comment: Please add [mcve], without that it could be just about anything.

Comment: Do you have to use the default browser styles? If not, you can achieve a similar effect (crossbrowser) with usage of `outline: none` and `button:active, button:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px aqua}`, see https://jsfiddle.net/t46bpvu8/

Comment: No. This is an option.